# Error while creating bean

Tags: spring-mvc, threadpoolexecutor

I have written one mail utility for my project. Now when I try to

```
@Autowired
EmailManager emailManager
```

from my UserController I am getting the error saying that the bean can not be created.
here I am displaying the code written in Class EmailManager

```
@Component
public class EmailManager {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmailManager.class);

    public boolean sendChangePasswordNotification(String password,UserVO userVo) throws Exception{
        try {
            logger.info("Send change password notification to " + userVo.getEmailId());

            String cc = PropertyUtil.getProperty("cc");
            logger.info("cc:"+cc);

            HashMap<String,String> replaceKeyValue = new HashMap<String,String>();
            replaceKeyValue.put("username", userVo.getUsername());
            replaceKeyValue.put("password", password);
            replaceKeyValue.put("firstName", userVo.getFirstName());

            HashMap<String,String> recipientMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            recipientMap.put("to", userVo.getEmailId());
            recipientMap.put("cc", cc);

            MailThread sender1 = (MailThread) appContext.getBean(MailThread.class);
            sender1.setEmailOption(Constants.SEND_CHANGE_PASSWORD_NOTIFICATION);
            sender1.setRecipientDetails(recipientMap);
            sender1.setReplaceKeyValue(replaceKeyValue);

            taskExecutor.execute(sender1);
            logger.info("Sent change password notification to " + userVo.getEmailId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error", e);
            throw e;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the full stack trace which I got on eclipse console:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emailManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor com.isynergy.tasktrac.notification.EmailManager.taskExecutor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor com.isynergy.tasktrac.notification.EmailManager.taskExecutor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
```

How can I tackle this problem any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmailManager can't be created since it has declared a dependency for *ThreadPoolTaskExecutor*, and no applicable beans of that type is present in the application context. You need to create a bean of type *ThreadPoolTaskExecutor* to the application context.

Comment: Woaah, Amazing... This solved my problem.. Thank you..!!